# I cannot import from another file

Tags: python, import

I am making a soccer game. I am new to Python. I am trying to make soccerplayers on a file, then import it to my main game.

Here is soccerplayer.py

```
class soccerp:
def __init__(self,overall,name,speed,shoot,ballc,defence):
    self.overall = overall
    self.name = name
    self.speed = speed
    self.shoot = shoot
    self.ballc = ballc
    self.defence = defence
```

Here is soccerkeeper.py

```
class soccerk:
def __init__(self,overall,name,dive,reactspeed,reach,jump):
    self.overall = overall
    self.name = name
    self.dive = dive
    self.reactspeed = reactspeed
    self.reach = reach
    self.jump = jump
```

Here is soccerplayerlist.py

```
from soccerplayer import soccerp
from soccerkeeper import soccerk
#name overall speed shootingpower ballcontrol defence
david = soccerp("david",114,181,179,183,148)
john = soccerp("john",119,179,185,187,151)
soccerplayers = [david,john]
```

And here is my game.py

```
import time
from soccerplayerlist import soccerplayers
#name overall speed shootingpower ballcontrol defence

ovr = [120,124,158,132,109] #will edit as the players overalls
teamovr = round(sum(ovr) / len(ovr))

def start():
    print("Please pick your teams name : ")
    team = input(">  ")
    print("")
    time.sleep(1)
    return team

def menu(team):
    print("teams name : " + team)
    print("team overall : " + str(teamovr))

def game():
    team = start()
    #while True:
    teamovr = round(sum(ovr) / len(ovr))
    menu(team)
    print(david.name) #checking if the players were imported from soccerplayerlist.py

game()
```

when I run the code, It says

```
NameError: name 'david' is not defined
```

I think that it didnt import the players, I may be wrong, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think it's importing wrong, I think that there is a problem in your code. Is `player` a class? Is `keeper`? Otherwise, I'm a bit confused as to why you use player and keeper and not self

Comment: i changed it to self just now

Comment: keeper doesnt really matter im working on soccerplayer.py for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're importing the list and not the values of the list.
If you do

```py
print(soccerplayers[0].name)
```

You should get the desired result.

Comment: how do i import the values of list?

Comment: If you import the list you’ll get the values, but not the names. The problem is that you’re trying to access it from the variable name i.e. `from soccerplayerlist import david`

Comment: but I will make hundreds of players. and I dont want to make hundreds of imports on a code, thats why i tried to make a list and import the list because I thought that if i saved all the players in a list, i maybe could acess the players by using import only once. how can I not use hundreds of imports but still have hundreds of players?

Comment: Using a list is a good approach, you'll just have to access them via the list (like in my answer) rather than via the variable name

Answer (score 0):

The name david is not the one you import it is the list of soccerplayers
what you can do is instead of this line.

```py
print(david.name)
```

do this:

```py
for player in soccerplayers: 
    if player.name == "david":
        david = player
```

I personaly recommend on pygame it is a library in python which allows to make high level games.

Comment: did the code work ?